# Variadic function calling a variadic macro

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I have an inline variadic function

`inline int foo(...)`

I need `foo()` to call a macro (let's call it `MACRO`), which is also variadic. 

 Basically I need `foo()` to pass all its input parameters to `MACRO`. Redefining `foo()` as another macro would be an easy solution because of `__VA_ARGS__` option, but I also need `foo()` to return a value.

Note: I am trying to interface two parts of already written code and I am not allowed to change them. `foo(...)` is used in the first part of code and `MACRO` is defined in the second part. Only thing I am supposed to do is to define a `foo()` which uses `MACRO` and I can't because they are both variadic.

Comment: Can you use variadic template for `foo` instead of ellipsis ?

Comment: Are you talking about varargs or variadic function templates ? With one your problem can be solved, with the other it can't.

Comment: Can't be done. Function parameters are set at run-time, macros are expanded before compilation. I'd throw this mess away and figure out a sensible way of doing whatever it's trying to do.

Comment: I am not familiar with variadic templates sir, let me check

Comment: yes, I can use variadic template for foo, but I couldn't get it to compile when I pass the input parameters to the variadic macro

Comment: Could you show `MACRO` ? Does it substitution is broken with `args...` ?

Answer (score 7):

Make `foo` a macro that contains a lambda that returns a value, and then invokes that lambda.

```
#define foo(...) \
  [&](auto&&...args){ \
    /* do something with args, or __VA_ARGS__ */ \
    MACRO(__VA_ARGS__); \
    return 7; \
  }(__VA_ARGS__)
```

now `int x = foo(a, b, c);` will both call the lambda inside `foo`, and inside that lambda call the macro on `(a, b, c)`, and can return a value.

I pity whomever maintains your code next.

Comment: Note that `args...` and `__VA_ARGS__` may differ for cases like `foo(arg1, (extra, parenthesis, around, comma, operator, arg2));` or simple `foo(function_with_side_effect())`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yep!  The `auto&&....args` and `(__VA_ARGS__)` is optional, and can cause unpredictable side effects.  Still, it gives you the arguments as arguments, as well as as tokens, which I figure is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is impossible.

A variadic function's arguments are determined at runtime, but a macro expands at compile time.

Comment: Impossible?  This is C++.

Comment: @Yakk It __is__ impossible. Read his question again. `foo` needs to be a function, not a macro.

Comment: "Because `foo` must return a value."  All we need is a macro that returns a value then! Sacrifice 3 virgin goats on the mars solistice and call me in the morning.  Or, you know, summon abominations with C++ code.  Either works.